# UITableViewCell selected row's text color change

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am having a tableview and I want to know that how can I change the selected row's text color, say to Red ? I tried by this code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell= [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

    cell.text = [localArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cityName = [localArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell* theCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    theCell.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    //theCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

(1) When I select any row then text color changed to the red but when I select another then previously selected row's text remains red. how can I solve this ?

(2) When I scroll the table text color change to the black color how to solve this ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Do this in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

(And don't use `cell.text = ...` anymore. It has been deprecated for almost 2 years now. Use `cell.textLabel.text = ...` instead.)

---

As [Raphael Oliveira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1792327/raphael-oliveira) mentioned in the comments, if the selectionStyle of your cell equals `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` this won't work. Check Storyboard as well for the selection style.

Comment: the color should be red until I select another row !

Comment: Worths mentioning that if the selectionStyle of your cell equals UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone this won't work. You might not have added this code but check in Storyboard to not waste a lot of time like me trying to figure out why this isn't working.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the text colour only, with out changing cell background colour. you can use this.Write this code in in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: I'm using this method, but on iOS 10 setting the selectedBackgroundView color causes the table separators to disappear on selection. I'm still working on a good solution to this side effect.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, try this!

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    for (id object in cell.superview.subviews) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            UITableViewCell *cellNotSelected = (UITableViewCell*)object;
            cellNotSelected.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

That may be the solution to your (and mine) problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already subclassing `UITableViewCell`, it's easier/cleaner to  set the colors in the `awakeFromNib` method (assuming you're instantiating from a storyboard or xib).

```
@implementation MySubclassTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    self.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.308 blue:0.173 alpha:0.6];
    self.customLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

@end
```