# Change TableView cell labels' highlightedTextColor globally?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got a fairly large iOS app with dozens of subclassed TableViews, and now my boss says that he'd like to change the text color of highlighted rows across the whole app.

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841082/1418688), the way to do that is to change the `highlightedTextColor` property within each textLabel of the table's cells.  But for my app, we're talking about 2-3 labels per cell type, and dozens of tables.  I could obviously change each one manually, adding lines for each label for each tableView individually, but I'd prefer not to be found by future archeologists as a cobweb-covered skeleton at my desk.

Is it possible to change a global setting to alter the default `highlightedTextColor` across the whole app?  I'd happily change the ones I want to change and deal with any issues, rather than going through and adding three versions of

```
cell.firsttextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whateverColorMyBossWantsNowColor];
```

to every `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method in the app...

Comment: Are you using a custom class for these cells? You should be instead of manually adding the labels in various `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods.

Comment: I do have custom cells, but they're working correctly already.  It's the  default cells that aren't changing their text colors when the row is selected, so I'm hoping that there's a default setting I can change that will fix that for all the default-style cells.

Comment: Try using the appearance proxy to set the text color for all labels in table cells.

Comment: Don't do it for all labels. use `appearanceWhenContainedIn` to limit it to table cells.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Per rmaddy's comment, I just put

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:UITableViewCellStyleDefault, UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle, nil] setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

into the AppDelegate method `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, and it seems to have fixed it!

I don't have a lot of experience with appearance proxies, but I'll sure be looking into them now!